# Need to show two separate info on one select HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show these two array in two text field when selecting one option. 
What is happening now is its just showing the first array, it needs to show two array on the input tags when creating country is selected.

```js
var host_country_start = {
  "Afghanistan":"21-Dec_start",
  "Albania":"01-Jan_start",
  "Algeria":"01-Jan_startz",
};
var host_country_end = {
  "Afghanistan":"21-Dec_end",
  "Albania":"test_end",
  "Algeria":"test2_end",
};

var selectbox = document.getElementById('host_country');
var textbox = document.getElementById('host_country_date');

selectbox.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  textbox.value = host_country_start[this.value]
})
```

```html
<span id="s_home_country">                   
  <select name="Host Country" id="host_country">
    <option value="Select one" selected="selected">Select one</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
  </select>
</span>

<label>Start Date:</label><input id="host_country_date" type="text" />
<label>End Date:</label><input id="host_country_end_date" type="text" />
```

Comment: Provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Why? When the code can be run right here in SO? Please don't advise users to post their code elsewhere. Those external links may become invalid in the future and then the questions here will be useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the reference to the another array and include it in your code.

```js
var host_country_start = {
  "Afghanistan":"21-Dec_start",
  "Albania":"01-Jan_start",
  "Algeria":"01-Jan_startz",
};
var host_country_end = {
  "Afghanistan":"21-Dec_end",
  "Albania":"test_end",
  "Algeria":"test2_end",
};

var selectbox = document.getElementById('host_country');
var textbox = document.getElementById('host_country_date');
var textbox2 = document.getElementById('host_country_end_date');

selectbox.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  textbox.value = host_country_start[this.value];
  textbox2.value = host_country_end[this.value];
})
```

```html
<span id="s_home_country">                   
  <select name="Host Country" id="host_country">
    <option disabled value="Select one" selected="selected">Select one</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
  </select>
</span>

<label>Start Date:</label><input id="host_country_date" type="text" />
<label>End Date:</label><input id="host_country_end_date" type="text" />
```

Comment: Holy... it worked!! And thank you for the fast reply. I really appreciate it! Thanks guys!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks Kind user!

Comment: @CarloViloria My pleasure, my dear friend! :)

Comment: @CarloViloria By the way, would you like to mark my answer as the best one? I need rep points :D

Comment: @CarloViloria Have a great day, my dear friend!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get a reference to the second text field and add an additional line of code in your event handler that sets its value using the same technique as you did with the first textbox, but accessing the second array instead of the first.

```js
var host_country_start = {
  "Afghanistan":"21-Dec_start",
  "Albania":"01-Jan_start",
  "Algeria":"01-Jan_startz",
};

var host_country_end = {
  "Afghanistan":"21-Dec_end",
  "Albania":"test_end",
  "Algeria":"test2_end",
};

var selectbox = document.getElementById('host_country');
var start = document.getElementById('host_country_date');
var end = document.getElementById('host_country_end_date');

selectbox.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  start.value = host_country_start[this.value];
  end.value = host_country_end[this.value];
})
```

```html
<span id="s_home_country">                   
  <select name="Host Country" id="host_country">
    <option value="Select one" selected="selected">Select one</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
  </select>
</span>

<label>Start Date:</label><input id="host_country_date" type="text" />
<label>End Date:</label><input id="host_country_end_date" type="text" />
```

Comment: @CarloViloria You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as the answer. Good luck!